# Parse column value of class is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

While fetching object using query only certain columns are fetched and the rest is nil. I have also tried `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` but with no luck.

Query:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Order")
query.whereKey("buyerUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (orders: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if(error == nil){
        print(orders?.first)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Optional(<Order: 0x7ff778011940, objectId: KytyBZD9zV, localId: (null)> {
buyerUser = "<PFUser: 0x7ff77353e520, objectId: xxxxx, localId: (null)>";
charged = 1;
fulfilled = 0;
item = "<Item: 0x7ff778011dd0, objectId: GN277W4mO0, localId: (null)>";
shippingUser = "<PFUser: 0x7ff778012270, objectId: xxxx, localId: (null)>";
stripePaymentId = "xxxxxx";})
```

`Order` class in Parse Data Browser

[image: Order Class]

If I try to access the `transactionId` with following code:

```
let order = orders?.first
print(order.objectForKey("transactionId"))
```

The result is always `nil`.

Please help.

**Update**

Attached is the `Order` class data in Parse. As all the rows have data and the object I have used have returned some data in other columns (buyerUser, charged) there is data in `transactionId` column of the object.

[image: Parse Order Class Data]

Comment: @sushithe is there any data in the parse data browser for transactionId? Or is it an empty column at the moment

Comment: @Sushilthe, Can you test this `print(order["transactionId"])`? I believe the problem is that you are dealing with a `PFObject` class object as a dictionary.

Comment: @KelvinLau See his comment on on Girish Kolari's answer.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could share structure of your parse class named Orders. Because in the printing of the PFObject I dont see anything for transactionId in your shared log.

Comment: @KelvinLau: There are data present.

Comment: @sushithe Do this for me. Unwrap the `orders` array by using `guard let orders = order else { fatalError() }`

and then loop through the orders and let me know if you see a transactionId:

`for order in orders { print(order["transactionId"]) }`

Comment: @NSNoob: `print(order["transactionId"])` gives result: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: That means that your transactionId does not exist at least for this specific PFObject while it may exist for other objects of this same class.  It is also evident from your own print log that **your PFObject does not contain any transaction ID**. Double check that does the transaction ID hold some value in data browser for **this object**?

Comment: And existence of column does not necessarily mean that it would contain some value in it against some entry as well.

Comment: @NSNoob: I don't know what you are trying to prove, but I have value in transactionId column for every row in parse. Also, the transactionId is a must have value and is never nil/empty in any transaction related app.

Comment: I am not trying to prove anything I am only making my assessment based on the data you provided. You did ask the community members to help right? Unless I am mistaken of course. If you are absolutely sure that for **this object** there is definitely data in column, then do explain why Parse is not returning it with the object? And I don't know why you are taking that tone when I am rising legit points based on the very limited data that you are providing. Show us this object in the data browser if you are sure transaction is not nil and we will all be satisfied.

Comment: And keep in mind I am talking about this object! Not the whole class!

Comment: @NSNoob: Look at my updates

Comment: @sushilthe see you are still confusing the whole class for an object. I want to see the object where objectId is `KytyBZD9zV` . The one that you are printing. It is not there in the screenshot. Filter it in your data browser.

Comment: @NSNoob: I don't know what is going on but even if I print the second order, the result is: 

`<Order: 0x7fb253fedc80, objectId: WrgiDFxZW6, localId: (null)> { buyerUser = "<PFUser: 0x7fb253d6f8e0, objectId: l11Q6H6Eyg, localId: (null)>"; charged = 1; fulfilled = 0; item = "<Item: 0x7fb253fed730, objectId: qvnHJVkoZ5, localId: (null)>"; shippingUser = "<PFUser: 0x7fb253fee830, objectId: o5iFjg9hIe, localId: (null)>"; stripePaymentId = "xxxxxxxx"; }`

and the objectId `WrgiDFxZW6 ` is not in the Parse.

Comment: Well I can't make any comment on what might be going on there for obvious reasons but it appears you have design and data integrity issues in your backend. `rigType` is also not included in the output.

Comment: @NSNoob: Not only the `rigType` if I create a new column it doesn't get included.

Comment: objectId : WrgiDFxZW6 - I can not locate it in screen shot you have attached.

Comment: Have you tried using ParseUI? And querying from a PFQueryTableViewController? I query using this function which is a subclass of the class:    `override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery` and always, without fault the queries work.  Maybe try that?

Answer (score 4):

I can not see "transactionId" in the console message you posted - if key you are looking for is not present it will return nil

> charged = 1; fulfilled = 0; item = ""; shippingUser = ""; stripePaymentId =
>   "xxxxxx";})

Update:
Server information and message in the console don'e match
eq: Order: 0x7fb253fedc80, objectId: WrgiDFxZW6 which can not be located in the server data attached with question.

It can happen if your are referring different table in Parse SDK than the one you used in web(screen shot) - make sure you are refereeing same table in code and web.

Comment: The problem is, I cannot see the key in the console while the column is present in the Parse Data Browser.

Comment: Presence of column does not mean it will necessarily contain data as well unless you have done complete flawless form validation and written some cloud code to reject an entry with a nil transaction id. Grish Kolari is right it is not there in your log.