# Unable to get value of Parse.com column

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is the craziest error I've encountered ever. I am trying to get the value from a column called nameRetailer in the Orders table, but it keeps getting nil.

Other columns of same String type are returning properly including the status column shown below.

What could lead to this? The spelling is certainly correct. Please help....

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = object?.objectForKey("dueDate") as! NSDate
        let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

        cell.retailerName.text = object?.objectForKey("nameRetailer") as? String
        cell.orderDueDate.text = strDate
        cell.orderStatus.text = object?.objectForKey("status") as? String
```

When I tried to print the value of object?.objectForKey("nameRetailer"), it shows nil in console. In the parse data browser, column has data and was refreshed.

[image]

Update: Adding additional code:

The entire class code responsible for the table view:

```
class OrderViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Orders")
        query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrdersTableViewCell


        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = object?.objectForKey("dueDate") as! NSDate
        let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

        cell.retailerName.text = object?.objectForKey("nameRetailer") as? String
        cell.orderDueDate.text = strDate
        cell.orderStatus.text = object?.objectForKey("status") as? String

        print(object)

        //let imageFile = object?.objectForKey("image") as PFFile
        //cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named:"placeholder") 
        //cell.cellImageView.file = imageFile
        //cell.cellImageView.loadInBackground()
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count
        {
            return 44
        }

        let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        return height
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count
        {
            self.loadNextPage()
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

An image of the table of orders:

[image]

and here is the log snapshot of printing PFObject:

[image]

And here is the updated snapshots showing the two rows

[image]

Comment: Two rows having retailer name don't necessarily mean that whole column will have retailer name. Show us the object in Data browser, for which retailer name is returned nil.

Comment: There are only 2 rows and each record has multiple columns and one of them is nameRetailer shown above. How come status column showing and all others showing except this?

Comment: When you print the PFObject, can you see retailers name in there?

Comment: @NSNoob no it doesn't show...@_@

Comment: @NSNoob also created additional column just for test...not showing in PFObject print

Comment: Okay so you say there are only two objects in the class. You say both of them have the name. And then you say it is not present in the PFObject you are using. Doesn't make any sense. One of these claims is not true. Please share code of how you are retrieving the PFObject and how are you processing it afterwards to populate your tableview. But there has been a question like this before. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772407/parse-column-value-of-class-is-always-nil?rq=1)

Comment: Can't see the object Ids in that Screenshot. To identify the objects, take a SS with their Object Ids. Also add the log printing of the PFObjects. Since there are only two, it should be very simple

Comment: Two things to check: are you using the right table? Would it not be a cache issue?

Comment: of course it is the right table! all the columns are showing except this one. As per the cache suggestion, maybe. How can I solve that?

Comment: @jcaron solved it! brilliant suggestion for the cache. I had this line         query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork which caused the issue. removed it and all is viewing. Post as answer and I will select it.

Comment: Change `query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork` to `query.cachePolicy = .NetworkOnly` to force reload from server

Comment: @jcaron post as answer

Comment: @jcaron eye of an eagle ;) Great catch mate

Comment: @NSNoob Thanks for helping

Comment: No problem Ksa_coder. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set your cache policy to start by looking up data in the local cache, which may be stale.

Change:

```
    query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
```

to

```
    query.cachePolicy = .NetworkOnly // ignores cache on reading, but saves to cache
```

or

```
    query.cachePolicy = .IgnoreCache // no cache at all -- this is the default
```

(or other appropriate value based on your specific context and use case)